# Using current_user in a scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, lambda, scope

My `User` model `has_many` `messages` I would like to retrieve the model's unread messages as a relation so I can chain it

at the moment, the only thing that worked for me is

```
class Message

scope :unread, lambda{ |user| where("receiver_open = false AND received_messageable_id = ?", user.id)}
```

and then access it as

```
current_user.messages.unread(current_user)
```

you can see that this is a bit smelly

Is there way to make the scope use the current_user which I used to invoke the scope? so that it would be `current_user.messages.unread`

Answer (score 0):

As, you are already filtering the messages using **current_user.messages** no need to filter the messages again.

Better to write scope without lambda

```
scope :unread, where("receiver_open = false")
```

Hope, it will help.

Comment: but I must check `received_messageable_id`

Comment: why you need received_messageable_id, is it not the same as user_id?

Comment: a message has a sender and receiver. so I want to check that current_user is the receiver

Comment: then what does current_user.messages returns?

Comment: can you try, scope :unread, where(:receiver_open => false,:received_messageable_id => self.user_id)

Comment: that gives `NoMethodError: undefined method user_id for #<Class:0x6aeb028>`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. scope :unread, where("messages.receiver_open = false AND messages.received_messageable_id = messages.user_id") works. It will find out the messages where receiver and user id is same.

Answer (score 0):

even if you could access the `current_user` variable form your model:
the model shouldn't know anything about who is currently using your app.

I think a simple solution would be to use only the *received messages* instead of *all messages*, so you won't have to check the identity of the receiver.

alternatively, calling your scope `unread_by` will make it more understandable and also less smelly.